# C++ sum of vector values (recursive)

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

The following could is intended to sum the ints in a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int arraySum(std::vector<int> vec, std::vector<int>::iterator start, std::vector<int>::iterator finish)
{
    if (vec.size()==1)
    {

       return vec[0];
    }
    else
    {
        if (start!=finish)
        {
            return *start + arraySum(vec, start+1, finish);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intVec(5);
    intVec[0] = 1;
    intVec[1] = 2;
    intVec[2] = 3;
    intVec[3] = 4;
    intVec[4] = 5;


    std::cout << arraySum(intVec, intVec.begin(), intVec.end());

    return 0;
}
```

At the moment, this is returning nonsensical values, like 7-digit numbers, to the console.

Please don't provide a complete and detailed solution, but rather some hints. Small snippets of code are also fine.

Comment: you don't need to pass the vector if you already pass `intVec.begin()` and `intVec.end()`

Comment: And the size of the vector remains unchanged anyway, so that itself should be a hint that using the vector an an argument, testing it's `size()` and expecting it to change, is wrong.

Comment: You do realize that since all parameters get passed by value, each recursive call creates a brand new copy of the vector, right? And the iterators are to the very first, original vector, that was created in `main`? What do you expect to accomplish by such an endeavor? P.S. Any compiler worth its salt will issue a warning message that explains exactly what your bug is. Did you get any warning messages from your compiler? If not, find a better C++ compiler. And if you did, this will be a pretty good life's lesson never to ignore compiler warnings, even if it still ends up compiling the code.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware. If you have two iterators, you can get the size of the iterator range they form with `std::distance(start, finish)` (requires `#include<iterator>`), so you don't need `vec.size()`. Or for random access iterators, such as here, `finish - start` also gives you the distance.

Comment: Please provide the compiler output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning a value for all paths in your recursion.

If a function is supposed to return a value, like an `int` in your case, you need to return one for all conditions in your function. You're lacking one for the case where `start == finish`.

In that case the function is probably returning a garbage value, which you are adding to your sum.

Simply adding `return 0;` at the end of the function solves this for me, because you only reach that stage if `start == finish`.

It's important to diagnose warnings as they arise, they very often show problems or bugs in your code. If you don't see any, I highly recommend adding warning flags to your compiler, making it easier to catch these kind of bugs, I would add at least `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: While the suggestion to add `-Wall -Wextra` certainly is a very good one, all three major compilers (clang, gcc, msvc) already warn for this particular issue, even without any flags, at least recent versions. Either OP is using an old compiler version or has ignored the warnings. GCC before version 8.1 seems to be the exception here.

Answer (score 0):

With help from the answers/comments provided, the code in the function is now the following. I am posting it here for the benefit of future readers of this question:

```
int arraySum(std::vector<int>::iterator start, std::vector<int>::iterator finish, int sum)
{
    if (start != finish)
    {
        sum += *start;
        return arraySum(++start, finish, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `sum` variable. If you just use `return *start + arraySum(vec, start+1, finish);` as you had before and returned `0` in the `else` branch (as mentioned in the answer by ShadowMitia), then the code would have worked as well.